# include raw text in http get request in c# backend code

Tags: c#, .net, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

I have this code:

```
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1232/vendor/70?minorversion=8");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                         = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "bLpuw.vjbvIP_P7Vyj4ziSGa3Ohg");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1232/query?minorversion=8").Result)
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    var json = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
```

Per the quickbooks api Postman sample they include raw text query in the http post action. 
Example: [image]

How can I include the raw text in my c# post request?

Comment: For that you can use the second parameter of the `HttpClient.PostAsync` method.

Comment: Is that your actual authentication code? You may want to remove that.

Comment: @scottheckel nope, modified authentication code but thanks for checking :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass content to `PostAsync` method just like this

```
var myContent = "your string in here";
var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);

using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1232/query?minorversion=8",bytecontent).Result)
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    var json = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1232/vendor/70?minorversion=8");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "bLpuw.vjbvIP_P7Vyj4ziSGa3Ohg");

var postContent = new StringContent("myContent");

using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1232/query?minorversion=8", postContent).Result)
{
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        var json = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Also, please be aware that you have some wrong use of the Async methods, you should always await instead of using the blocking `Result` property from the task.

Answer (score 0):

Create a StringContent() with the text in it and pass it to the PostAsync().

You might need to check what Content-Type header is expected and pass that to the StringContent constructor as well.

E.g.

```
using (var requestContent = new StringContent(“any text”, Encoding.UTF8, “text/plain”))
{
      ... httpClient.PostAsync(url, requestContent)...
}
```